# Cannot match any routes: '' angular 2 asp.net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

I have a one main page and I want to separate header body and footer. Because in other page I wont be needed header.

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
<main-app></main-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import { EqualValidator } from "./Validation/equal.validator.directive";
import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./Components/home.component";
import { DashBoardComponent } from "./Components/dashBoard.Component";
import { FooterComponent } from "./Components/footer.Component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home/Index', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'Account/Login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'Home/Index', component: HomeComponent,children:[
            {path: '',component: FooterComponent,outlet: 'footer'}]},
    { path: 'DashBoard/Index', component: DashBoardComponent}
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoginComponent, HomeComponent, DashBoardComponent, EqualValidator,FooterComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If I remove the child routing the application works good. I have added the forChild() root also but the footer component is not been loaded.

Here I found the working sample

https://plnkr.co/edit/sgGDpti43GPM5cHntPpu?p=preview
 But I am facing the **Cannot match any routes: ''** error

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
        selector: 'Home-app',
        template: `
        <br>
       <br>
       <br>

        my home!!!!

       <br>
       <br>
       <br>

    <router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
      `
    })

    export class HomeComponent {


    }
```

**footer.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'Footer-app',
    templateUrl: '<p>Copy rights emakitri 2017</p>'
})
export class FooterComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some code and explain in detail?

Comment: please find the added code ...